# Optimizing build time in Android Studio

Tags: maven, android-studio, build, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've tried building it:

- parallel (helps a bit)
- daemon=true
- preDexLibraries true/false ( no big difference )
- incremental true
- offline

It takes >40s EVERY time. It doesn't matter if I change anything or not. Building it after "gradle clean" takes >50s.

I hope that I'm doing something wrong. Eclipse/ant could build consecutive builds WITH CHANGES in <10s.

Any help how to bring this <10s appreciated.
Yes, we have a lot of modules, some jar libraries, some maven dependancies. Still don't get why would it take >40s for two consecutive builds with no changes.

Gradle used: 2.2.1
Android studio: not really relevant, usually building it only with Gradle.

EDIT: adding some profiling logs.

> :app:dexProjDebug                      22.541s
>
> :app:shrinkProjDebugMultiDexComponents 4.279s
>
> :app:compileProjDebugJava              3.478s
>
> :app:packageProjDebug                  2.591s
>
> :app:processProjDebugResources         2.590s
>
> :app:packageAllProjDebugClassesForMultiDex 2.536s
>
> :app:createProjDebugMainDexClassList   2.126s

Comment: The bounty is to get more traction.

Comment: Does your build script contain many custom tasks? In this case it is possible that these are not configured correctly so Gradle fail to recognize when the tasks are up to date? Can you share the script and/or its output?

Comment: No custom tasks. Just a bunch of library projects with source code (8) and several more projects used directly as gradle/maven dependancies.

Comment: dexOptions {
        incremental true //tried false as well
        preDexLibraries false // tried true as well
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode true
    }

Comment: Have you tried building with `--profile` to see where all the time is spent? This creates a report in build/reports that shows time for each task and whether it was up-to-date or not.

Comment: Adding the first lines of the profile logs to the question.

Comment: Another guess is that you have a task which its inputs/outputs are not configures properly. If this is the root of a long dependency chain then this can be the reason. This can usually be easily analyzed by checking which of the tasks is not up-to-date although it should be. If you'll share the output of the build I'll be glad to take a look.

Comment: Any news with your build?

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly define inputs and outputs even for library projects with source code. ([Gradle Documentation)](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks). Do you get UP-TO-DATE message when you rebuild second time onwards?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no changes to the other modules, you can build the app itself using `gradlew :app:build`. This will eliminate the time Gradle spends on building the other modules. You can build any module separately like this as well, using `gradlew :moduledirectoryname:build`. If you need to build one module and the app, you can execute both tasks at once to avoid going through Gradle's configuration stage twice: `gradlew :app:build :moduledirectoryname:build`

Answer (score 1):

If possible, update to Gradle 2.4. It's significantly faster (claiming 20-40%).

Answer (score 1):

One of the most significant build time reducers is the preDex task. Check whether preDex is running in your build. It increases build time the first time you run it, but dramatically reduces build times in subsequent builds, as most of your SDKs and libraries will already be dexed. Note however that it won't run under some conditions, e.g. if you use multidex.

Btw Google are well aware of build times with Gradle and Android Studio and are going to introduce significant improvements in upcoming releases, including Jack and Jill which will allow compiling from source code directly to dex. You can already try to experiment with them - see here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/jackandjill.

Also worth watching this video from recent Google I/O: https://youtu.be/f7ihSQ44WO0?t=327

Answer (score 0):

Download Genymotion emulator. It is very fast and good to run android apps. It will save you a lot of time.
Here is the link - [GenyMotionDownload](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download)